# Bean Transaction Timeout in WebSphere using EJB Timer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timeout, websphere, ejb-3.0

With JBoss/Wildfly one is able to use the `@TransactionTimeout` proprietary annotation and define a transaction timeout for a specific Session Bean.

What is the equivalent way of doing it using **IBM WebSphere**?

We are using EJB Timer and one of the Beans will over an hour to complete.

Sample code for Wildfly:

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;

@Stateless
@TransactionTimeout(value=7200)
public class TimerBean {

}
```

*Note: Using WebSphere 8.5. Modifying the global transaction time is not an option, we need to do it for a specific Session Bean, or maybe an Application (EAR).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can set it via `transaction-time-out` in custom extension `ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml` file.

In that file define:

```
<session name="TimerBean">
        <global-transaction transaction-time-out="7200"/>
</session>
```

> **Component Transaction Timeout**
>       For enterprise beans that use container-managed transactions only, specifies the transaction timeout, in seconds, for any new global
>   transaction that the container starts on behalf of the enterprise
>   bean. For transactions started on behalf of the component, the
>   Component Transaction Timeout setting overrides the default total
>   transaction lifetime timeout that is configured in the transaction
>   service settings for the application server.

For more details check [Configuring transactional deployment attributes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjta_entra2.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-9-6-1-0&lang=en)

Comment: The reference link is no longer valid; here's a current page for WebSphere 9.0.5: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=beans-ejb-30-ejb-31-application-bindings-overview#cejbbindingsejbfp__EJBextensions