# Overwrite WebSphere default transaction timeout

Tags: transactions, timeout, ejb, websphere

I have an application on WebSphere, the default transaction is 150 second, I don't want to change it.
But I have an EJB timer, sometimes it takes a bit too long(more than 150 second) to finish and throws a TimeoutException.

How can I overwrite the transaction timeout only for this method/bean?

```
@Timeout
public void mainService(Timer time) {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following StackOverflow post provides an answer to this question:

[Bean Transaction Timeout in WebSphere using EJB Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094890/bean-transaction-timeout-in-websphere-using-ejb-timer)

That post doesn't give a full example of an ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml file, which can be difficult to find, so I'll include one here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-ext xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-ext_1_1.xsd" version="1.1">
    <session name="YourSessionBean">
        <global-transaction transaction-time-out="300"/>
    </session>
</ejb-jar-ext>
```

You will need to substitute in your bean name and place the ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml file, if you don't already have one, alongside your EJB deployment descriptor ejb-jar.xml

Comment: Note: the configuration in `ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml` will set the transaction timeout for the bean. If you absolutely only want to change it for the one method, then you must convert the bean to use bean managed transactions, then use `javax.transaction.UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout()` in the method. This will of course require all methods to change and use UserTransaction to manage transactions, and the bean would not be able to participate in transactions started externally to the bean methods.